# configuring maximum inter-item spacing programmatically (swift 3.0)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Currently, whenever I create cells in my UICollectionView there is a constant vertical spacing between each cell. I want to remove this spacing between the cells. Researching similar questions and the documentation, I found out that this spacing comes from  an instance property; minimumInterItemSpacing, and that the default value for it is 10. Apparently there are two methods to go about changing this value,

using

```
collection​View(_:​layout:​minimum​Interitem​Spacing​For​Section​At:​)
```

which I did attempt to implement...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 0
}
```

and also,

directly setting the minimum​Interitem​Spacing property.

Using...

```
var minimumInteritemSpacing: CGFloat { get set }
```

Maybe I am implementing them wrong but the spacing still persists.
Noteworthy information, I am using swift 3.0 and the class is subclassed as a UICollectionViewController and UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it programatically when you instantiate the subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, you can do it:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

let collectionViewController = MyCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
```

If your class isn't a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, you can create your own `collectionView` (don't forget to implement `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocols):

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    let uicv = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    uicv.delegate = self
    uicv.dataSource = self
    uicv.backgroundColor = .white

    return uicv
}()
```

---

UPDATE

There is another way to do accomplish that if you are using a subclass of `UICollectionViewController`, you can implement this in your `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayou as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

Comment: My class is a class of type UICollectionViewController, but I'm still having trouble implementing it. I get the error Cannot use instance member 'layout' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: Can you further explain your second method?

Comment: @Stefan I updated my answer with another way to accomplish what you want.